# Wanted to edit an object of class in parse using javascript in webpage

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

```
    var UserInfo = Parse.Object.extend("UserInfo");
    var query = new Parse.Query("UserInfo");
    query.equalTo("userId", userId);
    query.first({
               success: function(result){

                result.save(null, {
                        success: function (result) {
                        result.set("name",name);
                        result.set("age",age);
                        result.save();
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                        }
                        });
               },
                error: function(error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
               });
```

Trying to update "name" and "age" of UserInfo class in my webpage. 
userId is different from objectId.
Error showing: 400 (Bad Request)

Anybody already done this or having any idea please revert with solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the response of your request, probably you don't specify authorization headers